# PHP code to alter or change URL

Tags: php, html, apache, http, .htaccess

Does anyone know how I can change th architecture of my site url? I use Apache server and php 5.3 I have a site that outputs url as shown below

```
http://localhost/index.php?articleId=23
```

I want it to be outputting the url like

```
http://localhost/articles/hot-news-of-the-day
```

please give me a url to refer to for tutorials, pdf or even a sample code. U can also give me a sample code. Anything. Please!!!

Comment: You will need `.htaccess`, and a script which maps article IDs to human-readable URLs, and vice versa.

Comment: http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ maybe can help you

Comment: this has got to be previously asked and explained. search for apache mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into URL Routing

A similar post is located here [PHP Application URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125677/php-application-url-routing)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `mod_rewrite` kind of stuff. Here's a **[link](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)** to a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Look at apache mod_rewrite module:

[Beginners guide to mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)

[Apache rewriting guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 1):

Within an .htaccess file in the root of your website folder you could use the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L]
```

and use a routing script that will match your URL parameters to the corresponding functions. Easier yet, try using a framework that will do this for you, such as [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using apache you'll need [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) file (or you could put it directly into configuration, it'll have better performance).

I recommend studying at least how [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) works (if you want use `.htaccess`).

You will be using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), main and most important command is [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (though you may use we rewrite Conditions). You should also google for [`mod_rewrite tutorials`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mod+rewrite+tutorials), but basic example how your `.htaccess` file should look like is:

```
# Turn on rewirting
RewriteEngine On

# Not file, not directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

# map /articles/* to index.php?article_title=*
RewriteRule ^/articles/(.+)$ /index.php?article_title=$1 [L]
```