# Get data from mysql db by slug url not id

Tags: php, mysql, slug

Im facing problem in getting data from mysql db by slug url. When i get data from id it works fine. I substituted urlslug also but no use.

Im trying to change my site article url(s)

```
mysite.com/public.php?id=12    to    mysite.com/public/google-search
```

My table:

```
+----+---------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | title         | article |   urlslug  VARCHAR 500 NULL        |
+----+---------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| 12 | google search | xxxxxxx |   google-search                    |
| 13 | bing yahoo    | xxxxxxx |   bing-yahoo                       |
| 14 | friendly seo  | xxxxxxx |   friendly-seo                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

code to get data by id:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo ($row['title']);
echo ($row['article']);    }
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need to parse the url to get 'google-search' and set that in the variable for your db call. Php has a bunch of built in functions to handle that.

Comment: I want to remove `.php?id=` and want to change to this `mysite.com/public/google-search` I dont know a possible way to get this. Im new to this.

Comment: if your server is `Apache`, then google for `.htaccess` files and `URL Rewriting`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, Here you go

When a user goes here....

```
mysite.com/public/google-search
```

This rewrite code will change the server side to this

```
mysite.com/public.php?id=12
```

By adding this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^public/google-search mysite.com/public.php?id=12 [NC]
```

You would need to do this for all files that you want to mask.

Comment: I want to remove `.php?id=` and want to change to this `mysite.com/public/google-search`

Answer (score 0):

You should make your route function, this links may help you:
http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/

[PHP Application URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125677/php-application-url-routing)

Comment: This smells a lot like a "link-only answer" and risks being removed (or converted to a comment).