# Rewrite my url to a dynamic one

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am having a url like

- https://www.example.com/profile.php?id=1064

I need to change this url to

- https://www.example.com/USERNAME.

This username is taken dynamically from the database with the entry id=1064

Please advice me a solution to rewrite my url to the above format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Application URL Routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125677/php-application-url-routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RewriteEngine on` in your `.htaccess` file to add `RewriteRule`s.  Have a look at Mod Rewrite:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.But can you please show me the code to do the same because I'm not aware about this rewriterule

Comment: It's very simple to learn, do some research.  You won't learn anything if I write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to have RewriteEngine on inside your `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

After that, you need the regular expression for your link. Supposing that all your username contains only letters and numbers, this will be the appropriate regular expression. However, if it's not the case, simply adjust the `[A-z0-9]` part to whatever characters your username can have.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9])/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Notice that we're passing the username as the $_GET param instead of the id.

Also, it's recommended to put something before the username in your link. In other words, http://example.com/u/username instead of http://example.com/username because if you have a page such as http://example.com/random, it's going to call the `profile.php` with `random` as the username. So for the example above, the regular expression would be:

```
RewriteRule ^u/([A-z0-9])/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```