# I have a URL, want to re-writing old url to new one

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a URL, looking below:

www.abc.com/postblog.php?url=xyz

I just want to remove [ postblog.php?url= ]. How i do this. i want my new url look like this:

www.abc.com/xyz

or

www.abc.com/blog/xyz

I am using a windows server, and i am applying both type of file web.config & .htaccess . Which one is worked and how i implement this url formation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: You can use [routes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125677/php-application-url-routing) and thus be server independant whether it's Apache, Nginx or anything else. You'll also need some [Regular Expressions](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) skills in order to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

*In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file.

Comment: I am using a windows server, and i am applying both type of file web.config & .htaccess . Which one is worked and how i implement this url formation.